# Fine Uploader Concurrent Chunking S3

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I've been trying to get this very Fine Uploader (fresh from NPM - 5.12.0-alpha) set up to push some data to S3 and I've been having some issues with chunking. I have enabled chunking I believe based on the example from [Concurrent Chunking](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/concurrent-chunking.html) but I have not seen multiple chunks being uploaded in the XHR console.

```
const fu = require('fine-uploader/lib/s3');
const SA = require('superagent');
let x = new fu.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
  request: {
    endpoint: 'they-taken-mah-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com'
  },
  credentials: {
    accessKey: 'invalid',
    expiration: new Date(),
    secretKey: 'invalid',
    sessionToken: 'invalid'
  },
  objectProperties: {
    bucket: 'they-taken-my-bucket',
    key: 'filename'
  },
  autoUpload: false,
  debug: true,
  callbacks: {
    onComplete: function(){
      moveUpload({from:'active', to:'finished', hash: activeUpload.hash}).then( function() { good(hash); });
    },
    onError: function(id, name, reason, xhrCache){
      moveUpload({from:'active', to:'error', hash: activeUpload.hash}).then( () => bad(new Error('upload error - '+reason)) );
    },
    onProgress: function(id, name, uploaded, total){
        const elapsed = (Date.now() - t.getTime()) / 1000;
        const rate = uploaded / elapsed;
        updateUploadProgress({hash: activeUpload.hash, progress: (100*uploaded/total).toFixed(0), rate: rate});
    },
    chunking: {
      enabled: true,
      concurrent: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    maxConnections: 5,
    retry: {
      enableAuto: true,
      maxAutoAttempts: 10
    },
    onCredentialsExpired: function () {
      return fetchCredentials();
    }
  }
});`
```

The behavior I'm seeing: http://recordit.co/z5VnLR63eT

Essentially I see the OPTIONS request, that goes fine, and the upload starts correctly but I only see 1 outbound connection - and the content type is not what I would expect, it's multipart form instead of raw. Though perhaps I'm wrong in this expectation, I would have expected it to just be a raw bin post.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: How big is the file? And are you only submitting one file?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought I attached that screenshot. Yes, it is only 1 file and it is 54MB. I would expect that with the default part size of ~5MB (according to the S3 doc) that it would split it up into 10 chunks and upload 3 (maxConnections) concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are not set correctly, and this is why concurrent chunking is not enabled.

You defined the `chunking` option inside of the `callbacks` section. Move it out of `callbacks` (along with `maxConnections` and `retry`).

Comment: Ha~ thank you very much. I'll delete this issue so my stupidity doesn't clutter the questions.